# Understanding acceptable advantage in MCDM method VIKOR

Tags: multicriteria-decision-analysis

As a distance-based MCDM method, unlike [TOPSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOPSIS), for [VIKOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIKOR_method), there is an "acceptability" check at the final step which confuses me, particularly for "Acceptable advantage", i.e., check if the first two ranked alternatives have sufficient gap.

> Acceptable advantage:$$Q(a'')-Q(a')\geq DQ$$ where $a''$ and $a'$ are alternatives with second and first position respectfully in the ranking list by $Q$; $DQ=1/(J-1)$; $J$ is the number of alternatives.

I'm curious why this is brought up in the method at first but other MCDM methods, e.g., TOPSIS, COPRAS, ELECTRE, have no such requirements. Well, I tried to find the original thesis *Opricovic, S. (1998) Multicriteria Optimization of Civil Engineering Systems. PhD Thesis, Faculty of Civil Engineering, Belgrade, 302 p.* but no luck.